# How can I find compound words, removing spaces between them and replace them in my corpus?

Tags: r, text-mining, corpus

I have many compound terms such as hello World, good Morning, good Night,... which I want to find them in my corpus and then replace them with their equivalent as helloWorld, goodMorning, goodNight. So in this way I can preserve their concept.
I can do it one by one, however its very tedious as there are many compound terms. I need to do this in R language.

Comment: What did you search? What did you find? What did you try so far? Please share some attempt.

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at `?gsub`

Comment: I have tried gsub but the problem is that I do not want to do this manually since it takes a lot of time. I have these terms in a text file, each compound term in a separate line , I am looking for some useful codes to take this text file and remove blanket between them then goes to my corpus and replace the compound terms with new terms (without blanket between terms)

Comment: I have tried this ,   for (j in seq(corpus))
{
  docs[[j]] <- gsub("simple parts", "simplepart", docs[[j]])
  
}   However if I wan to do this for every compound terms it will generate a very long lines of codes!

Comment: Only you know what compound terms you are looking for in your data, and not anyone else. I can't think of any logical set of keywords which would have 'helloworld' and 'goodnight' in it together without spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all your compound terms are separated only by blanks, you can use `gsub`:

```
> x = c("hello World", "good Morning", "good Night")
> y = gsub(pattern = " ", replacement = "", x = x)
> print(y)
[1] "helloWorld"  "goodMorning" "goodNight"
```

You can always add more patterns to `pattern` argument. Read more about regular expression in R [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/regex.html) and [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/rlanguage.html).

**Edit**

> @user4241750: True, but I only want to do this for particular compound
>   terms(There are many) not all the terms in the corpus since there are
>   many other terms in the corpus

If you know all particular compound terms you want to change, you can specify it on `docs[[j]]`. Say the only terms you want to change are "simple parts" and "good morning":

```
terms.to.change = c("simple parts","good morning")
for (j in seq(corpus)) {
  positions.to.change = which(docs[[j]] %in% terms.to.change)
  docs[[j]][positions.to.change] <- gsub(" ", "", docs[[j]][positions.to.change])
}
```

Comment: I have a Corpus which has 20 texts files, How can I apply these changes in my corpus with gsub?

Comment: I have tried gsub but the problem is that I do not want to do this manually since it takes a lot of time. I have these terms in a text file, each compound term in a separate line , I am looking for some useful codes to take this text file and remove blanket between them then goes to my corpus and replace the compound terms with new terms (without blanket between terms)

Comment: Could you give a simple example (in R code) of what you have exactly?

Comment: Thank you for reply. I have tried this , for (j in seq(corpus)) { docs[[j]] <- gsub("simple parts", "simplepart", docs[[j]]) } However if I want to do this for every compound terms it will generate a very long lines of codes.

Comment: If you do `for (j in seq(corpus)) { docs[[j]] <- gsub(" ", "", docs[[j]])}` all blanks will be removed. "simple parts" will become "simpleparts", "good morning" will become "goodmorning" and so on...

Comment: True, but I only want to do this for particular compound terms(There are many) not all the terms in the corpus since there are many other terms in the corpus.

Comment: I really do appreciate providing me with the codes, unfortunately due to the some reason it does not apply the change but do not throw any error! By the way docs in equivalent as corpus if it helps (docs<-corpus)